# How to create individuals of a specific class using Jena?

Tags: java, semantic-web, jena, ontology, protege

I've created an ontology using Protege and would now like to add individuals with Jena.

Let's say there is a class `SpecialThing` that has a property `hasData`. Now I'd like to programmatically add a new `SpecialThing`. That's my code so far, but the created individual is only an instance of `Thing`. So what do I have to add here? Using `model.createResource`I can only specify the URI of the resource to be created.

```
String ns = "http://example.org";
Resource res = model.createResource(ns + "/NewThing"); 
Property prop = model.getProperty(ns + "#hasData"); 
res.addProperty(prop, "something");
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Regardless of someone has already answered your question, I have a doubt. How do you set it directly to the .owl file? Do you know a tutorial for this task or can you publish the whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the type of the resource as a second argument to the createResource() method. Take a look at [ModelCon.createResource()](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelCon.html#createResource%28java.lang.String,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource%29)

Answer (score 3):

There is `OntModel.createIndividual()` **method** which does that.